# Creating Silverlight Designer

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight

I am creating a workflow SilverLight Web Designer.
I created a custom shapes, lets say it is a rectangle. I can add these shapes dynamically to the main canvas that is placed on the page.
I want to create a link between the two shapes, so i used the line object with the MouseLeftButtonDown, MouseLeftButtonUp and MouseMove events to draw the line between the two objects.
When Moving any one of the shapes i have to move all the lines connected to it. I did it.
**I just want to know if there is an easier way or a common way, maybe more professional way to do this behavior.**

Comment: Originally, I wanted to achieve the same kind of thing. WPF has a built in workflow designer. I am assuming you are talking about a designer for Windows Workflow. Is this correct? But, I have to ask the question: Why Silverlight? You won't be able to run the workflow in Silverlight. So, my suggestion is to take the path of least resistance and create an editor in WPF. Yes, this is extra installation for your clients, but it's really not that much of a big deal considering that .NET is installed on all Windows computers while Silverlight isn't, and will be sunsetted soon.